# Type mismatch error on IE8?

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe

I have a page with an iframe.

The iframe resides on the same domain so no x-domain issues.

I need the iframe to copy some of its contents to the parent.

So I have the parent page with the iframe like so

```
...
<div id="some-content">
  <iframe src="frame-1.html" style="display:none;"></iframe>
</div>
...
```

And this is the frame-1.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div name="content">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x250/ffffff/E8117F&text=from+frame+1" />
  </div>
  <script>
    (function() {
      var content = document.getElementsByName("content")[0];
      var iframeName = this.name;
      var iframeContainer = parent.document.getElementsByName(iframeName)[0].parentNode;0
      iframeContainer.appendChild(content);
    })();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

It works fine on modern browsers but fails on IE8/9?

I imagine the type mismatch comes from the **content** variable not being of type node?

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what Error you get in Console??

Comment: "Type mismatch" is the error verbatim

Comment: `name` is not a supported property of `div`.. that's probably why it's having problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a problem with `getElementsByName` try instead `querySelectorAll`. It works in IE8.

```
var content = document.querySelectorAll('[name="content"]')[0];
```

CSS selectors are very powerful, and IE8 supports enough of them to be very useful.

The only requirement for the attribute selector to work in IE8 is to use the HTML5 doctype,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

which - on older browsers - is interpenetrated as strict HTML4.